# What game is this die from

Tags: identify-this-game-piece

Please help me identify this die.

[image: image of gaming die]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You are more likely to get a good answer if you provide more details - at the very least, what symbols are printed on the other six faces?

Comment: It's something Marvel related, that being Thanos' face.

Answer (score 11):

It looks to be from Marvel Battleworld - here's an image of [a very similar dice on its BoardGameGeek listing](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/5529873/marvel-battleworld) (and certainly one in the same style).

Comment: Not the same die, as the numbers and positions don't work out (OP's image shows 1-5 around the thanos symbol. BGG shows a 10 clearly next to the thanos symbol)

Comment: @Andrew [This image](https://cf.geekdo-images.com/_pPNETKEWmjjn0U-eZsq-A__large/img/Bya9zQ4OexRD2PXSX0coWE7-owE=/fit-in/1024x1024/filters:no_upscale():strip_icc()/pic5488204.jpg) shows that the game has multiple dice, and that they don’t all have the same arrangement of numbers as each other.

Comment: @Andrew fair point - edited my answer accordingly.